# Which OData Provider to use

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have successfully used the [WCF Data Services Toolkit](http://wcfdstoolkit.codeplex.com/) in the past, but I realize that it might be a dead project (last modification on Codeplex was May 2011).

The successor seems to be the [Microsoft ASP.NET Web API OData](http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.webapi.odata) provider which is being developed as part of the broader Web API effort.

I need to expose a custom OData service as part of a SharePoint solution, so **easy packaging inside a WSP** would be preferable. I have tried to expose the WCF DST but haven't succeeded yet.

Is the **Web API OData provider ready for production use (in a few months time)?**

Any pointers to resources that show how to install a Web API OData endpoint as part of a SharePoint WSP?

**Note:** SharePoint 2010 (our current production target) is built in .NET 3.5 which might prevent Web API from being used.

Comment: Just a note: WCF Data Services is not dead; that toolkit hasn't been updated in a while, but WCF DS itself is shipping regularly via [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Services/)

Answer (score 3):

Definitely `Microsoft ASP.NET Web API OData` - it's currently at RC on Nuget, but you can grab the latest bits off the nightly build feed - the nightly builds already contain a much more mature version.

The Nuget nightly build feed is http://www.myget.org/F/aspnetwebstacknightly/

The official release will ship soon - (no exact date set yet) but the team is targeting mid-February.

Comment: Too bad it requires .NET 4.0 which prevents it from being integrated directly into SharePoint 2010 (forgot to mention that in my original question).

Comment: Yes, everything Web API related is .NET 4.0 since it's based around the new HTTP object model, rather than the old stuff from System.Web.dll.

Comment: Ok, I will keep Web API in mind when we move our product to SharePoint 2013, but in the meantime it sounds like I am stuck with trying to get WCF Data Services to deploy correctly with SharePoint 2010.